# How to handle concurrence when call Exchange web service

Tags: concurrency, exchangewebservices

We have an application which can book appointment in Exchange by EWS(Exchange web service), we use following code to book

```
CheckAppointmentsIsBookedInSameTime();
var appointment = new Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment(ExchangeService);
...
appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy);
```

The CheckAppointmentsIsBookedInSameTime will get all booked appointments and check if an appointment was booked in same time. It will throw exception if a appointment was booked.

Currently it have concurrence problem. Two user can book same appointment in same time range if they do operation in same time.  The book result is one is accept, one is declined.

My question is, during an appointment is in booking(in progress, but not done), how do we check the appointment in booking if another guy want to booking same appointment in same time?

Comment: I don't understand your question. If two appointments are booked, you want one to fail, right? What exactly happens now?

Comment: @Istanfin my question is, during an appointment is in booking(in progress, but not done), how do we check it in booking if another one want to booking same appointment in same time?